# Unable to save Chat Messages in Core Data Table XMPPRostar.sqllite

Tags: xcode, core-data, xmppframework

Following warning comes in logs:

:[logging] BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /Users/startelelogic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1811D170-B826-48F9-94A0-36C0BC16B59C/data/Containers/Data/Application/5532AFE6-4467-4865-9351-4B5251A1D0E8/Library/Application Support/com.bigtown.bigtown/XMPPRoster.sqlite

Comment: Please take a moment to review this carefully: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague to have a specific answer. However the message *"vnode unlinked while in use"* suggests that you have removed the SQLite file while some of your code is attempting to use it.

Why that's happening is impossible to say from your question.